# Good pattern or architecture for types and subtypes of game entities?

Tags: objective-c, c, game-engine

Let's say I have planets in a game, I also have spaceships. I have spaceships which are pirates and I have shuttles which are spaceships. I have planets which are pirate planets as well. Obviously I could add a switch for each type and add subtypes etc. but it seems like it gets muddy quickly.

Stuff like:
A hub is a planet
A planet is not a hub
A hub can be a pirate
A ship can be a pirate
A shuttle can be a ship
A ship cannot be a shuttle

Inheritance of types and subtypes. I currently do a combination of subclasses and types, but it becomes hard to keep it simple and robust I think.

Is there a good pattern or architecture for these kinds of complex type systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental approach is to figure out what entities have features in common, and make sure they inherit from the same base class.

For instance, all ships and planets orbit something, so they could all inherit from `SpaceBornObject`.

Space stations, planets, ships, and so on could then all inherit from this.

At the same time; space stations and ships are both constructed; so they could also inherit from a common class, or one of them from another.

Shuttles and pirate ships don't really need to be separate classes; this is where composition comes into play:

Consider a `Faction` class; and then having on, say, `SpaceBornObject` a field `Faction *controlledBy;`, or something to that effect.

Comment: So far this is what I have been doing, I was praying there was some clever way to do it. I have some really fundamental objects that everything inherits from, but it probably wouldn't hurt to sit down and refactor some of it. Thank you for the answer :)